# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Failed to get a connection using the URL '192.168.1.133:3306'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am just trying to run a simple unit test which requires database connection.

```
private static MysqlDataSource dataSource=new MysqlDataSource();

@BeforeEach
void setUpBefore() throws Exception {       
    dataSource.setURL("192.168.1.133:3306");
    dataSource.setUser("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
}
```

and late in the actual unit test

```
map=new MenuDAO(dataSource.getConnection()).getMenu(); //throws exception
```

I do have MySQL Workbench successfully connect to MySQL database with the above settings. However when JUnit executes the test I get the following exception. Not sure why.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Failed to get a connection using the URL '192.168.1.133:3306'.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:413)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:136)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:107)
    at com.m2ii.MenuService.dao.test.MenuDAO_UT.testGetMenu(MenuDAO_UT.java:41)
```

Comment: That's not a URL. No scheme. It should start with `jdbc:mysql://`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setURL method needs to have a little bit more. Make it `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.133:3306`